# How can i fix connection timed out on kali linux?

Tags: operating-systems, kali-linux, error-correction

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo apt-get update         
[sudo] password for kali: 
Get:1 http://deb.i2p2.no unstable InRelease [19.7 kB]
Ign:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease                                                              
Ign:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Ign:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Err:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  Could not connect to http.kali.org:80 (192.99.200.113), connection timed out
Fetched 19.7 kB in 37s (527 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://deb.i2p2.no/dists/unstable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  Could not connect to http.kali.org:80 (192.99.200.113), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Check your Internet Connection. You are not connected. Kali updates are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same error, and had tried replacing default repositories present in /etc/apt/sources.list ... i run kali on VM and had even tried re-installing kali multiple times ... after a lot of frustration and research  this is the solution that worked for me finally...

step 1. open terminal and type.... sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

step 2. delete everything present inside (you might have read not to tamper with this file as it can cause kali to not function properly...but anyway what have you got to lose)

step 3. put in these mirror repositories...

```
 deb http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
#deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

step 4. save and type sudo apt update

hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).